# Cumulative Adding in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is what i have got in my SQL SERVER database table, where I am trying to calculate Balance Leave of an employee.
My actual data is:

```
EmpId EmpName   EvalDate                OpeningEL   EnjoyedEL   BalanceEL
12    CHANDRA   2014-04-01 18:30:00.000  0.95       0.00         0.95
12    CHANDRA   2014-05-01 18:30:00.000  1.30       0.00         1.30
12    CHANDRA   2014-06-01 18:30:00.000  1.20       1.00         1.20
12    CHANDRA   2014-07-01 18:30:00.000  1.25       0.00         1.25
12    CHANDRA   2014-08-01 18:30:00.000  1.25       1.00         1.25
```

But i need the data in below way

```
EmpId EmpName   EvalDate                OpeningEL   EnjoyedEL   BalanceEL
12    CHANDRA   2014-04-01 18:30:00.000  0.95       0.00         0.95
12    CHANDRA   2014-05-01 18:30:00.000  2.25       0.00         2.25
12    CHANDRA   2014-06-01 18:30:00.000  3.45       1.00         2.45
12    CHANDRA   2014-07-01 18:30:00.000  3.70       0.00         3.70
12    CHANDRA   2014-08-01 18:30:00.000  4.95       1.00         3.95
```

Previous BalanceELs are added with next OpeningELs.

So, how to achieve this....Please suggest something.

Comment: there is no `EL  with 1.00` in your input data

Comment: @ughai: I didn't get you... can you plz elaborate more..

Comment: In your source data, there is no record with EnjoyedEL as 1. However In our output there are 2 records with EnjoyedEL  as 1.

Comment: @ughai: oh...sorry...now i have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` and `GROUP BY` to achieve this

`OpeningEL` and `BalanceEL` from `CROSS APPLY` will get the sum of current and previous records for an employee.

```
SELECT
    EL1.EmpId,
    EL1.EmpName,
    EL1.EvalDate,
    Temp.OpeningEL,
    EL1.EnjoyedEL,
    Temp.BalanceEL
FROM EmployeeLeave EL1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
    SUM(OpeningEL) as OpeningEL,
    SUM(BalanceEL) - SUM(EnjoyedEL) as BalanceEL
    FROM EmployeeLeave EL2
    WHERE EL2.EmpId  = EL1.EmpId 
    AND EL2.EvalDate <= EL1.EvalDate
)Temp;
```

Comment: -"EL2.Prev_OpeningEL" this column is not present in both tables